# Migrate from Digital Ocean Space to Amazon AWS

Tags: php, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

**The goal**

I need to move thousands of objects from Digital Ocean Space to Amazon AWS. All files are images and the total size is around 36GBs.

**The problem i'm facing:**

Googling around I can see we can transfer from Amazon AWS to Digital Ocean Spaces, but not the other way around.

**What I'v found**

All codes I find are about upload several objects to a bucket but not download them from a bucket.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "move tons of info". Are they files, databases, objects? What about applications? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you, i'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't get it. Why the downvotes? Why people don't explain so I can improve my questions?

Comment: StackOverflow is primarily a forum for **software development**. It doesn't officially cater for IT systems questions, even though there's a lot of them that get answers. The definition of a downvote is _"This question does show show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."_ In its current form, that is quite correct.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I believe it is usefull, I haven't found in any other place, but I agree that this might not be the best place to ask this, thank you for your clarification. Should I delete my question?

Comment: No, you should clarify your question so that people can supply useful answers, from which other readers will benefit in future. Your question should include what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried and what difficulties you have encountered. At the moment, you have only stated what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks again, here it goes another update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon Digital Ocean's article [How To Migrate from Amazon S3 to DigitalOcean Spaces with rclone](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-amazon-s3-to-digitalocean-spaces-with-rclone), it seems that you can use [rclone](https://rclone.org/) to copy between the two services (in either direction).

Answer (score 1):

I already accepted John Rotestein's answer, but Digital Ocean answered my question as well.

There's a way to download all Digital Ocean spaces content in Windows with Cyberduck:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-digitalocean-spaces-with-cyberduck

Than you can build a script to loop your directory and send objects to Amazon AWS. If you don't know how, you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170895/moving-a-file-stored-locally-to-amazon-s3) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-php/).

**Update**
Cyberduck stucks after a while if you have too many files. SO i'm using S3EXPLORER from this link which also has installation instructions :- http://s3browser.com/download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using `rclone`. It was too complex so I built a PHP script to do this automatically. You need to have API key/secret for both DO Space/AWS Bucket and that's it.

https://gitlab.com/exevio-open-source/digitalocean-spaces-transfer

Worked great for my company when we migrated accounts with over 2TB of files.